# How can I replicate "select someinteger from foo where someinteger like '%50%' in Linq to entities?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that displays data in a table format. I want to give my users the ability to search the table, so I take a text string and pass it into my service layer to construct a query using Linq to Entities.

I want to search a number of columns using the string. Some of the columns are integers (order ids), but the user doesn't care about integers and strings. They want to type '1200' and get any order with '1200' in the order number, or '1200' in the address.

The problem is that I can't find a way to construct a Linq-to-Entities query that results in SQL that looks like this:

```
select orderid, address from orders where orderid like '%1200%' or address like '%1200%'
```

Database context:

```
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WorkerSignin> WorkerSignins { get; set; }
```

The `Persons` and `Workers` tables are in a 1 to 0..1 relationship. If a worker record exists, a person record must also exist. They share the same ID. A worker record doesn't have to exist, however.

The `Workers` and `WorkerSignins` tables are related, but it's not enforced because of a client requirement. The Worker has an id-card with a barcode number on it (`dwccardnum`), but there may be discrepancies between cards issued and records in the DB, so I record all cards scanned in `WorkerSignins`, regardless of whether there is a matching record in the `Workers` table.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
            allWSI = signinRepo.GetAllQ()
                .Where(jj => jj.dateforsignin == date)
                .Select(a => a);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                allWSI = allWSI
                    .Join(workerRepo.GetAllQ(), s => s.dwccardnum, w => w.dwccardnum, (s, w) => new { s, w })
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .Join(personRepo.GetAllQ(), oj => oj.w.ID, p => p.ID, (oj, p) => new { oj, p }).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .Where(jj => Convert.ToString(jj.oj.w.dwccardnum).Contains(search) ||
                                jj.p.firstname1.Contains(search) ||
                                jj.p.firstname2.Contains(search) ||
                                jj.p.lastname1.Contains(search) ||
                                jj.p.lastname2.Contains(search))
                    .Select(a => a.oj.s);
            }
```

The GetAllQ() methods return an IQueryable() object.

The problem is on this line: 
    `.Where(jj => Convert.ToString(jj.oj.w.dwccardnum).Contains(search) ||`

I get this error:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

If I take out the convert, and try this:
    `.Where(jj => jj.oj.w.dwccardnum.Contains(search) ||`

I get this error:
'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

**So the question is...**
How do I construct a Where clause to generate a like '%string%' and execute it against a integer column using Linq to Entities? (e.g. without using LINQ to SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to replace ...

```
jj => Convert.ToString(jj.oj.w.dwccardnum).Contains(search)
```

... by:

```
jj => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)jj.oj.w.dwccardnum).Contains(search)
```

`SqlFunctions` is a static class in namespace `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` and I believe it only works with SQL Server. The weird cast to `decimal` is necessary because `StringConvert` doesn't have an overload for an `int` and without the cast the compiler complains that it cannot select the right overload unambiguously. (It has one for `decimal?` and one for `double?`.) But I just tested that the code above works indeed (with SQL Server and assuming dwccardnum is an `int`).

Comment: That does work. The SQL that the Object Services layer (I think that's the correct layer) looks pretty inefficient...may be time to bite the bullet and go with Expression Tree building...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                int cardnum;
                bool searchIsInt = int.TryParse(search, out cardnum);

                allWSI = allWSI
                    .Join(workerRepo.GetAllQ(), s => s.dwccardnum, w => w.dwccardnum, (s, w) => new { s, w })
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .Join(personRepo.GetAllQ(), oj => oj.w.ID, p => p.ID, (oj, p) => new { oj, p }).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .Where(jj => (searchIsInt ? jj.oj.w.dwccardnum == cardnum : true) ||
                                jj.p.firstname1.Contains(search) ||
                                jj.p.firstname2.Contains(search) ||
                                jj.p.lastname1.Contains(search) ||
                                jj.p.lastname2.Contains(search))
                    .Select(a => a.oj.s);
            }
```

Basically, you're first checking to see if the search is an int and then use it in your linq if it is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's not what I'm looking for, because (I don't believe) the integer comparison (==) will get partial matches. If the user enters '120' in the search string, I want to match 120, 1201, 1202,851201, etc. 

I don't believe what you're proposing will lead to the `like '%120%' in the resulting SQL...I'll go try it though.

Comment: You're right about the partial search, 120 will only look for 120 and not 1201. Also I had a syntax error -> added cardnum as out parameter